# How to refresh fragment it is added to viewpager, when I press back button in another fragment(it is not in viewpager)

Tags: android, fragment, onbackpressed

How to refresh Fragment1 when I pressed back button in Fragment2.Here Fragement1 is added to View Pager inside Activity class. Both Fagments are under android.app.Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go around this is via `Fragment` communication which involves the host `Activity` as the `middleman` for example :

```
interface FragmentCommunicator {
    fun refreshFragmentOne()
}

class MyActivity : Activity(), FragmentCommunicator {
    override fun refreshFragmentOne() {
        val fragmentOne = pageAdapter.instantiateItem(pager,1) as? FragmentOne?
        fragmentOne?.refresh()
    }
}

class FragmentTwo : Fragment() {
    var listener : FragmentCommunicator? = null
    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        listener = context as FragmentCommunicator
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        listener = null
        super.onDetach()
    }
}
```

now in your `Button#onClick` call `listener?.refreshFragmentOne()`

for more details please read https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0):

try to refresh fragment when it visible to user.
Override `setUserVisibleHint`method in your fragment1